# Ruby/Rspec: should be_false vs should == false

Tags: ruby, object, rspec

Here's my code:

```
class Dictionary
  def entries
    @entries ||= {}
  end

  def add(hash)
    if hash.class == Hash
      hash.each_pair do |k, v|
        entries[k] = v
      end
    else
      makehash = {hash => nil}
      self.add(makehash)
    end
    @entries = entries
  end

  def keywords
    @entries.keys
  end

  def include?(k)
    if @entries == nil
      false
    elsif self.keywords.include?(k)
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

And here's the test I'm running it against:

```
require 'dictionary'

describe Dictionary do
  before do
    @d = Dictionary.new
  end

  it 'can check whether a given keyword exists' do
    @d.include?('fish').should be_false
  end
```

Now, that test will fail. However, if I change it to

```
  it 'can check whether a given keyword exists' do
    @d.include?('fish').should == false
  end
```

then it passes.

How can I change my code so that `should be_false` passes instead of `should == false`? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `should be_false`? Also you probably should use `@d.should include 'fish'`

Comment: @BroiSatse My apologies. `should be_false` is what I meant to put in the original post. I've edited it. I want to get `should be_false` to work.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995582/command-be-true-seems-not-to-work-in-rspec-2-1

Comment: @arealhumanbean - What rspec version are you using?

Comment: for `be_false` you should create method that respond to `false`.

Comment: @UriAgassi I appreciate the post. However, I would like to understand what's going on behind the scenes that's causing it to fail. Is there a way to make the test pass without changing it?

Comment: `receiver.should be_xxx` is translated by default to something more or less equivalent to `receiver.xxx?.should == true`. Boolean does not support `.false?` so the test fails...

Comment: I believe I'm using rspec 3.0.3 but I'm not sure. I remember having to downgrade something ruby related to get something to work but the details escape me. `rspec -v` in terminal gives me 3.0.3, though.

Comment: @arealhumanbean - What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: @BroiSatse
can check whether a given keyword exists (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Dictionary can check whether a given keyword exists
     Failure/Error: @d.include?('fish').should be_false
       expected false to respond to \`false?\`
     # ./11_dictionary/dictionary_spec.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: Then @UriAgassi comment is explaining what's going on here. To see the version of the rspec run `bundle show rspec`, or if you are not using bundler (you should!) `gem show rspec`

Comment: If you use `rspec > 3.0`, `be_false` should be changed to `be_falsey`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`be_false` matches falsey values (`nil` and `false`) and
`be_true` matches truthy values (other than `nil` or `false`)

From Rspec > 3.0,

`be_false` is renamed to `be_falsey` and

`be_true` is renamed to `be_truthy`

If you want to exactly match `false`, you should use

```
obj.should eq false
```

See the [Documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/built-in-matchers/be-matchers) for more info about 'be' matchers

Comment: Added more info to the answer. :)